# How can you prove this by strong induction?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, recursion

The sequence $b_1,b_2,...$ is defined recursively as:\begin{align} b_1&=0;\\ b_2&=1;\\ b_n&=2b_{n-1}-2b_{n-2}-1 \ \text{for} \ n\geq3. \end{align} Prove that this means: $$\forall n\geq1: b_n=(\sqrt{2})^n \sin{\left(\frac{1}{4}\pi n \right)}-1$$

Edit:

I have tried to prove this by strong induction and have verified than $P(1)$ and $P(2)$ is true, where $P(n)$ is the statement $b_n=(\sqrt{2})^n \sin{\left(\frac{1}{4}\pi n \right)}-1$.

edit: I have assumed that $P(k-2)$ and $P(k-1)$ is true for $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then I have managed to simplify to: $$b_n=(\sqrt{2})^n \left[\sqrt{2}\sin{\left(\frac{1}{4}\pi (n-1) \right)}- \sin{\left(\frac{1}{4}\pi (n-2) \right)}\right]-5$$

I can't simplify any further.

Comment: Tried simplifying $2b_{n-1}-2b_{n-2}-1$ after plugging in the expression? Looks straightforward.

Comment: Since you are using strong induction and you proved $P(1)$ and $P(2)$, you can assume $P(n-1)$ and $P(n-2)$ to hold for $n\ge3$ and check if $P(n)$ holds under these assumptions.

Comment: If necessary you could use several different cases to deal with the fact that the sine term is periodic.

Comment: @Macavity I have tried to simply but I can't produce $\sin{\left(\frac{1}{4}\pi n \right)}$.

Comment: $\sin(\pi n/4)$ is $\pm 1,\pm \frac1{\sqrt2}$ or $0$, depending on $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have verified the base case, we proceed to the inductive case. Fix $n >2$ and suppose that for all $k <n$, $P(k)$ is true. We want to show that $P(n)$ is true.

$$
\begin{aligned}
b_{n}&=2b_{n-1}-2b_{n-2}-1\\
&=2\left((\sqrt{2})^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{1}{4}\pi (n-1)\right)-1\right)-2\left((\sqrt{2})^{n-2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{4}\pi (n-2)\right)-1\right)-1\\
&=(\sqrt{2})^{n}\left(\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi (n-1)}{4}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi (n-2)}{4}\right)\right) - 1
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, using $\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B$, we get

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi (n-1)}{4}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi (n-2)}{4}\right)=\\
&\sqrt{2}\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac{-\pi}{4}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{4}\right)\sin\left(\frac{-\pi}{4}\right)\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac{-\pi}{2}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{4}\right)\sin\left(\frac{-\pi}{2}\right)\\
&=\sqrt{2}\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{4}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{4}\right)(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}})\right)-\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{4}\right)\\
&=\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{4}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{4}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{4}\right)\\
&=\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{4}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Comment on the Approach in the Question**

The inductive step needs to show
$$
\begin{align}
2b_{n-1}-2b_{n-2}-1
&=2\left(2^{(n-1)/2}\sin\left(\tfrac{(n-1)\pi}4\right)-1\right)-2\left(2^{(n-2)/2}\sin\left(\tfrac{(n-2)\pi}4\right)-1\right)-1\\
&=2^{(n+1)/2}\sin\left(\tfrac{(n-1)\pi}4\right)-2^{n/2}\sin\left(\tfrac{(n-2)\pi}4\right)-1\\
&=2^{n/2}\left[\sqrt2\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}4\right)\cos\left(\frac\pi4\right)-\sqrt2\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}4\right)\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)\right]\\
&-2^{n/2}\left[\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}4\right)\cos\left(\frac\pi2\right)-\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}4\right)\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)\right]-1\\
&=2^{n/2}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}4\right)-1\\[3pt]
&=b_n
\end{align}
$$

---

**A Different Approach**

To solve
$$
b_n=2b_{n-1}-2b_{n-2}-1\tag{1}
$$
let $a_n=b_n+1$. Then
$$
a_n=2a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}\tag{2}
$$
which has the characteristic polynomial $x^2-2x+2$, whose roots are $1\pm i$. Therefore, the solutions to $(2)$ are
$$
a_n=\alpha(1+i)^n+\beta(1-i)^n\tag{3}
$$
and the solutions to $(1)$ are
$$
b_n=\alpha(1+i)^n+\beta(1-i)^n-1\tag{4}
$$
To satisfy $b_1=0$ and $b_2=1$, we compute $\alpha=-\frac i2$ and $\beta=\frac i2$.
Thus, we get
$$
b_n=-\frac i2(1+i)^n+\frac i2(1-i)^n-1\tag{5}
$$

---

**Changing the Form**

Starting from $(5)$, we get 
$$
\begin{align}
b_n
&=-\frac i2(1+i)^n+\frac i2(1-i)^n-1\\
&=\frac{e^{-i\pi/2}}22^{n/2}e^{in\pi/4}+\frac{e^{i\pi/2}}22^{n/2}e^{-in\pi/4}-1\\
&=2^{n/2}\cos\left(\frac{(n-2)\pi}4\right)-1\\
&=2^{n/2}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}4\right)-1\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: That's a very elegant second proof.